# /var/lib/ambari-server/keys/keystore.p12 file not being generated while starting ambari-server

Tags: apache, ambari

I've added a new stack in amabari-server and built it. now after installing the ambari-server rpm on new hosts, when i start ambari-server,
it give following error:

> 20 Jun 2016 16:25:53,020  INFO [main] Configuration:1067 - Web App DIR test /usr/lib/ambari-server/web
>   20 Jun 2016 16:25:53,027  INFO [main] CertificateManager:68 - Initialization of root certificate
>   20 Jun 2016 16:25:53,027  INFO [main] CertificateManager:70 - Certificate exists:false
>   20 Jun 2016 16:25:53,027  INFO [main] CertificateManager:137 - Generation of server certificate
>   20 Jun 2016 16:25:55,627  INFO [main] ShellCommandUtil:44 - Command openssl genrsa -des3 -passout pass:**** -out /var/lib/ambari-server/keys/ca.key 4096  was finished with exit code: 0 - the operation was completely successfully.
>   20 Jun 2016 16:25:55,644  INFO [main] ShellCommandUtil:44 - Command openssl req -passin pass:**** -new -key /var/lib/ambari-server/keys/ca.key -out /var/lib/ambari-server/keys/ca.csr -batch was finished with exit code: 0 - the operation was completely successfully.
>
> 20 Jun 2016 16:25:55,654  WARN [main] ShellCommandUtil:46 - Command openssl ca -create_serial -out /var/lib/ambari-server/keys/ca.crt -days 365 -keyfile /var/lib/ambari-server/keys/ca.key -key **** -selfsign -extensions jdk7_ca -config /var/lib/ambari-server/keys/ca.config -batch -infiles /var/lib/ambari-server/keys/ca.csr was finished with **exit code: 1** - **an error occurred parsing the command options.**
>
> 20 Jun 2016 16:25:55,663  WARN [main] ShellCommandUtil:46 - Command openssl pkcs12 -export -in /var/lib/ambari-server/keys/ca.crt -inkey /var/lib/ambari-server/keys/ca.key -certfile /var/lib/ambari-server/keys/ca.crt -out /var/lib/ambari-server/keys/keystore.p12 -password pass:**** -passin pass:****
>    was finished with exit code: 1 - an error occurred parsing the command options.
>   20 Jun 2016 16:25:55,696  INFO [main] AmbariServer:611 - Jetty is configuring qtp-ambari-agent with 4 reserved acceptors/selectors and a total pool size of 25 for 4 processors.
>   20 Jun 2016 16:25:55,717  INFO [main] ViewRegistry:1538 - Reading view archive /var/lib/ambari-server/resources/views/ambari-admin-2.2.2.1.0.jar.
>
> 20 Jun 2016 16:26:02,549  WARN [main] AbstractLifeCycle:204 - FAILED SslContextFactory@38aed8ad(/var/lib/ambari-server/keys/keystore.p12,/var/lib/ambari-server/keys/keystore.p12): java.io.FileNotFoundException: /var/lib/ambari-server/keys/keystore.p12 (No such file or directory)
>   java.io.FileNotFoundException: /var/lib/ambari-server/keys/keystore.p12 (No such file or directory)

Can anyone help with this? 
I'm using CentOS7 for ambari-installation.

Answer (score -1):

mkdir /var/lib/ambari-server/keys/db/newcerts/ ---- 
I met this problem when I install ambari with the RPM package that built by myself.
Then I find the answer of this question is that missing folder.
This folder missed when I clone the source from my git repository,because it's empty.
So, check the "newcerts" folder in your source or your ambari-server host

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please have a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer

Comment: I'm sad, I had this problem before and this is the right way to solve it.
Why hit me down?
You don't even know if i'm right!

Comment: Please read the link I provided, and put some context to your answer. And I did not downvote you.